# TableView is not rendering data

Tags: swift, cocoa, macos-sierra

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    let data = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
    ]

    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: NSTableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("init")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tbl.delegate = self
        tbl.dataSource = self
        tbl.target = self
        tbl.reloadData()
        print("end init")
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            tbl.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        if let cell = tbl.make(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
            if let col = Int(tableColumn!.identifier) {
                print("col id: ", tableColumn!.identifier)
                print(row, col)
                cell.textField?.stringValue = String(data[row][col])
                return cell
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        if let col = tableColumn {
            if let colIndex = Int(col.identifier) {
                print(data[row][colIndex])
                return data[row][colIndex] as Any
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
}
```

I am just trying to load a matrix into the table view, but it is blank when the app runs. What went wrong here? 
Judging from the debug info, the functions `tableView` were never invoked.

Comment: That's a poor topic without explaining your variables including an array you are using to populate the table.  How many columns do you have?  - We can't tell.

Comment: `voices` is the data used for populating the table.

Comment: That's not how you write tableView's objectValueFor method.

Comment: Just one column, containing the names for the voices.

Comment: Oh, sorry, voiceNameForIdentifier is a function.

Comment: I don't see tbl.reloadData() anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I see you set the delegate of the tableView, but I don't see where you set the data source of the tableView.